# Disable :set hlsearch when I enter INSERT mode

Tags: vim, search

I've set hlsearch on my .vimrc.

The problem is: when I find what I need in my document, I want it to automatically disable hlsearch when I enter insert mode for that searched string.

So, if I try to search for another string, it starts over again. This behavior is well known among other editors.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a completely different approach, but that's is EXACTLY what I was looking for.

```
:set hlsearch
autocmd InsertEnter * :let @/=""
autocmd InsertLeave * :let @/=""
```

> This sets the "latest search" register
>   to the empty string, so that nothing
>   will be highlighted. Earlier searches
>   can still be remembered by using the
>    key after hitting / or ? and
>   optionally the "start" of the string
>   to be searched.

[Source](http://old.nabble.com/hlsearch-question-td8556290.html)

Thanks for your answer [akira](https://superuser.com/questions/156248/disable-set-hlsearch-when-i-enter-insert-mode/156290#156290), but this solution is really elegant in my opinion. And it works, I tested it!

Comment: if it works, its fine with me.

Comment: This approach breaks the "search again" functionality (`/ <cr>`).

Answer (score 7):

disable highlighting when entering insertmode via <kbd>i</kbd>:

```
noremap i :set nohlsearch<CR>i
```

to reenable it by leaving insert mode (via <kbd>ESC</kbd>):

```
inoremap <ESC> <ESC>:set hlsearch<CR>
```

you could apply these idea to all kind of keys like <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd> etc.

OR

```
autocmd InsertEnter * :set nohlsearch
autocmd InsertLeave * :set hlsearch
```

(kudos for the 'InsertEnter' event idea)

Comment: Is there a Vim event that would be possible to add this config to avoid config to other keys?

Comment: InsertEnter and InsertLeave are interesting. I'm going to check them out. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-vim-script-5/index.html

Comment: true, good point.

Comment: You probably also want to use 'setlocal' instead of ':set'.  This will make it so that you dont modify the settings of other buffers.